# Add nodes in jcr on first login

Tags: jcr, jackrabbit, sling

I want to create nodes in jcr repository on first login. I have created my own LoginModulePlugin for authenticating a user. I am receiving a SystemSession (package org.apache.jackrabbit.core) while authenticating. This however does not have info about the repository I want to add nodes in
What would be the recommended approach to add the nodes to jcr on login?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you mean `javax.jcr.Session` since `SystemSession` is not public.

```
Session s = ...;
Node node = s.getRootNode().addNode("some/relative/path");
```

Comment: The session I am getting is `org.apache.jackrabbit.core.SystemSession`. While logging I am not able to create a new session (javax.jcr.Session) for the subject.

Comment: Though `SystemSession` extends the `SessionImpl` which in fact is an implementation of `Session`. See docs: http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.jackrabbit/jackrabbit-core/2.10.1/org/apache/jackrabbit/core/SystemSession.java?av=f

Answer (score 0):

You must get your session from the corresponding repository.
For me, something like this works:

```
private static Session instance = null;    
public static void login() {
  if (instance == null) {
    try {
      final Repository repository = JcrUtils.getRepository();
      instance = repository.login(new SimpleCredentials("admin", "admin".toCharArray()));
    } catch (RepositoryException e) {
      log.error(e.getMessage(),e);
    }
  }
}
```

Then you would put something like this when your program starts

```
Session s = login();
s.getRootNode().addNode("your/node/path");
s.save();
```

Getting the repository from the JcrUtils is the key.